# Unable Create Directory in CentOS using Java

Tags: java, jsp, centos, tomcat7

I'm creating a Web Application using Java Servlets. I used *JDK7, Tomcat7*. I was perfectly working till I hosted local site in windows. But when I migrated to *CentOS directory is Not creating.*

```
File outputFile = new File("/Data/");
try{
if(!outputFile.exists()){
    if(!outputFile.mkdir()){
        throw new UnableToCreateFolderException();
    }else{
        outputFile = new File("/Data/" + user);
        if(!outputFile.mkdir()){
            throw new UnableToCreateFolderException();
        }
    }
}else{
    outputFile = new File("/Data/" + user);
    if(!outputFile.exists()){
        if(!outputFile.mkdir()){
            throw new UnableToCreateFolderException();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I used in Windows. And I tried to create **"/Data"** directory and give full access to user and then I tried to run it.

Comment: You're trying to create a directory in the root folder. What is the user who is running your Tomcat? If that user does not have permissions to create that directory, then your code can not create that directory too.

Answer (score 0):

That path (`/Data`) is in the root directory, which the user you're running Tomcat as certainly shouldn't have write access to. It's always bad design to hard-code paths like this in your program; instead, you should read a property (such as `myapp.homedir`) and use that instead.

Answer (score -1):

Just execute this command and try again,

```
chmod 755 /Data
chmod 777 /Data/*
```

Comment: [Don't chmod 777](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318885/476716)